# Postgres dynamically transform specific columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions

We have a SQL server, but have decided to port everything over to a postgres server for a couple of reasons. I am having trouble recreating one of the SQL server stored procedures. Data is uploaded into the server on a daily basis. All decimal numbers in the raw data do not have the decimal points. The procedure dynamically figures out where to place the decimal  of by finding the precision from the columns' definition.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[adddecimal] @tableName varchar(30)
AS

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = ''

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'UPDATE ' + @tableName + ' SET ' + c.name + ' = ' + c.name + '/ power(10,'+CONVERT(varchar(10), c.scale) + ');'

FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types y ON c.system_type_id = y.system_type_id
WHERE t.name = @tableName AND y.name ='decimal';

exec(@sql);
```

the output of this follows this structure

```
  UPDATE table1 SET col1 = col1/power(10,3); UPDATE table1 SET col2 = col2/power(10,5)'.....
```

How can I do the equivalent in postgres??? Postgres doesn't want to concatenate all of the commands into a single executable. I get this error

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

This is what i have so far

```
CREATE FUNCTION clean_emp2() RETURNS void AS 
  $body$
DECLARE
   prec integer := (select numeric_scale from information_schema.columns) ;
   column_nm varchar(50) := (select column_name from information_schema.columns where data_type like 'numeric');
   table_nm varchar(50) := 'test_table'; // will eventually be pulled from function call

BEGIN 
    UPDATE table_nm set column_nm = column_nm / power(10,prec)
END $body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I know I'm fairly close to the solution, but I don't know how to get the procedure to return a string of multiple UPDATE statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the aggregate function `string_agg` to concatenate several result rows into one string.

Then the query will only return one row, which can be stored in a variable.

Comment: Would i place that in the BEGIN clause? something like BEGIN  string_agg(command, newest_str)

Comment: No. `SELECT 'UPDATE tabname SET ' || string_agg(<compose SET clause here>, ',') INTO sql FROM ...`. It is an aggregate like `sum`. Please see the documentation for details.